# add dhtmlxLayout to a div (page jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtmlx

I have a problem with adding a dhtmlxLayout to a div-element.
First to the structure of my pages. I load all pages in the following way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// #Load-Page 
   doLoadPage("pgLayout.html", "", "pgLayout", "CPgLayoutHandlers"); 
}

function doLoadPage(par1, par2, par3, par4) {
    $.mobile.loadPage(par1, { showLoadMsg: false });
   // handle other parameters...
}
```

During another function I init all pages, which I loaded before. The init function populates the current content div of a page with dhtmlxLayout and some other objects.

My problem is that the page doesn't show the layoutObject. In Firebug the lines for the layout are there but in gray. So it loads the objects in DOM.

Here is a screenshot
 [image: Firebug layoutobject is grey]

Info
If I add **only a dhtmlxGrid** to the divLayout it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `<div id="divLayout">` have initial zero height and its "collapsed", try to set some `style="height:Xpx;"` value to it.